# using std::launch::deferred does not defer the function in std::async

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous

https://godbolt.org/z/MEsandWGe

Here's the code I'm testing, same as the above godbolt link:

```
#include <future>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main() {
    int v = 0;

    auto a1 = std::async(
        std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred, [&v]() {
            std::cout << "begin 1" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "v = " << v << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms);
            std::cout << "end 1" << std::endl;
    });

    auto a2 = std::async(
        std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred, [&v]() {
            std::cout << "begin 2" << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(200ms);
            v = 123;
            std::cout << "end 2" << std::endl;
    });

    a2.wait();
    // My understanding is a1 does not run until here?
    // thus v should print 123 instead of 0 ?
    a1.wait();

    return 0;
}
```

If I remove the `async` policy, it works as expected.

The question is, why do I see `a1` running concurrently with `a2` and see `v` printed as `0`? Does the `async` policy affect the behavior of `deferred`?

Comment: [*"policy  -  bitmask value, where individual bits control the **allowed methods** of execution"*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) You're leaving the choice whether to launch as async or deferred up to `std::async`.

Comment: You have undefined behavior so all results are correct.  You cannot modify and read a variable in two different threads without using some sort of thread synchronization technique.  Using `std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred` may also be UB as you are telling `async` to use both `async` and `deferred` mode which our counter to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred` means that `std::async` can choose which of the two policies is selected. It is implementation defined which one is used but it looks like your standard library chooses `async` rather than `deferred`.

Comment: Thanks, just noticed the following on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)
`If more than one flag is set, it is implementation-defined which policy is selected`